# Can we identify generating elements of a group by observing the element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, finitely-generated, semidirect-product

When we consider the group $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$, a pair like $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ can generate the group. Also $\{(0,2),(3,0)\}$ can generate the group.

When we consider $(\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_3$, a set $\{((0,1),0), ((0,0),1)\}$ as well as $\{((0,2),0),((0,0),1)\}$ can be generating sets. Likewise there are many choices for generating elements. When we look at the first element in both of the above sets, we can observe their $y$- coordinates are 0, so that they must be of order 5. Hence, even if one doesn't specify that the above sets are generating sets we can identify that first two elements are possible candidates for order 5 generating elements. Similarly, we can identify the second two elements are order 3 generating elements.

As an example, if we have a sequence of elements,

$\{((0,3),0), ((0,0),1), ((2,1),0), ((1,1),2), ((2,3),2), ((0,0),2)\}$

By observing the $x$ and $y$ coordinates we can say that $((0,0),1), ((0,0),2)$ are possible candidates for order 3 generating elements and $((0,3),0), ((2,1),0)$ are possible candidates for order 5 generating elements (if I'm to arbitrarily select elements for a generating set with order 3 and order 5 generating elements).

Can we determine the generating or non-generating nature of other elements in the above sequence similarly by observation?

And if we have any semidirect product $H \rtimes_{\phi} K$ where $H,K$ are finite groups, the elements of the group are from $H \times K$, when written as ordered pairs like above.

If we are given a sequence of arbitrary elements like above can we always determine the possible candidates for generating elements by observing $x$ and $y$ coordinates like above (Suppose we know the groups $H,K$ and their orders)?

Comment: It might help of you said exactly what you mean by "the generating or non-generating nature" of an element or "candidates for generating elements". The standard meaning of a non-generator is an element of the Frattini subgroup $\Phi(G)$. Both of your examples have trivial $\Phi(G)$ so all elements (except the identity) could be regarded as candidates for generating elements.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you. I think I have meant as you have explained. By non-generating nature I meant that an element which can never be included in to any generating set. By candidate I meant that we can use $(0,2)$ in the generating set instead of using $(0,1)$ if we want to (when we consider the first example). So, $(0,2)$ is another candidate or a choice where I can choose $(0,2)$ as the generating element and write $\{(0,2),(1,0)\}$  as a generating set for the group instead of $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ etc.

Comment: By the above question I wanted to clarify: when considering a group $G =H \rtimes_{\phi} K$, unlike in the above examples, there can be groups $G$ where all elements aren't suitable candidates as generating elements. In such a case, if we give a sequence of elements including both generating elements and the elements which can't be included in any generating set, can a person who knows only the groups $H,K$ and the orders of $H,K$  identify which elements are the generating elements (perhaps by observing the $x$ and $y$ coordinates)?

Comment: P.S. :The person will know that these are elements from a semidirect product between $H$ and $K$ and $H$ is the normal subgroup and that the underlying set is $H \times K$. But not any information about $\phi$.

Comment: "An element which can never be included in to any generating set." There are no such elements. If $X$ is any generating set, and $g$ is any element then $X\cup\{g\}$ is also a generating set. The usual meaning of "non-generator" is that $g$ is a non-generator if, whenever $X$ is a generating set with $g\in X$, then $X\setminus\{g\}$ is *also* a generating set.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ok, thank you. When considering the non-generating elements as you have defined, if we get a sequence of elements from a semidirect product $H \rtimes_{\phi} K$ as I have mentioned earlier, can a person identify which elements are non-generators and the generating elements? Thanks a lot in advance.